# Объявление указателей

Tags: c, указатели

Правильно ли я понимаю, что конструкция

```
int *a, *b;
```

объявляет два указателя?

Такая конструкция

```
int* a, b;
```

аналогично объявляет два указателя.

Вопрос. Что делает такая конструкция?

```
int * a, b;
```

P.S. Я знаю, что так делать нельзя. Вопрос чисто академический.

Comment: В объявлении можно и так, все варианты имеют одинаковый смысл. Но более понятный для глаза - первый вариант.

Comment: @NewView А в ответе говорят про разный. Кому верить?

Comment: Анту конечно :) я имел в виду что все записи правильные, с точки зрения восприятия компилятором

Comment: @NewView Утверждения "все записи правильные с точки зрения компилятора" и "все варианты имеют одинаковый смысл" не эквивалентны

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Объявление

```
int *a, *b;
```

объявляет два указателя.

Объявление

```
int* a, b;
```

объявляет *один* указатель, а не два, как вы неправильно предположили. `b` в этом случае указателем не является.

При этом

```
int * a, b;
```

ничем не отличается от предыдущего варианта. Расстановка пробелов между элементами объявления никак не влияет на его интерпретацию.